# конструктор php

Tags: php

Использовать в одном классе конструкторы, объявленные методом __construct() и методами, совпадающим с именем класса

Comment: в чем вопрос???

Answer (score 1):

В PHP Нет перегрузки методов, т.е. конструктор может быть только один, в версиях до 5.6, конструктор может называться также как и имя класса

```
class Foo {
    public $str;

    public function foo($str){ 
        $this->str=$str;
    }

}

$foo =  new Foo('sdf');
var_dump($foo);
```

В версиях 7 и выше будет выдано предупреждение, что метод со схожим именем в будущем будет удален.

Ну а вообще можно сделать так и посмотреть, что сработает метод с именем __construct

```
class Foo {
    public $str;
    public $str1;

    public function __construct($str)
    {
        $this->str1 = $str;
    }

    public function foo($str){ 
        $this->str=$str;
    } 

}

$foo =  new Foo('sdf');
var_dump($foo);
```

Причем если задать методы в другом порядке, будет выдано предупреждение, что метод конструктор уже определен.

Ну и выдержка с [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php)

> В целях обратной совместимости, если PHP 5 не может обнаружить
>   объявленный метод __construct(), то вызов конструктора произойдет по
>   устаревшей схеме, через обращение к методу, имя которого соответствует
>   имени класса.